# Doctrine fixtures not working after updating to Symfony 2.1.8

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, fixtures

After updating a project from Symfony 2.0.22 to 2.1.8 I get this error when executing `doctrine:fixtures:load` via Terminal

> Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\Loader' not found in {symfony_install_folder}/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/DataFixtures/ContainerAwareLoader.php on line 27

The fixtures worked on 2.0.22 and I've checked [the official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) to see if I've set everything correctly

My **composer.json** looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.1.8",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.5-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.3.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.1.*",
        "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.1.*",
        "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
        "doctrine/common": "2.4.*@dev",
        "doctrine/data-fixtures": "2.0.*@dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "dev-master",
        "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "2.3.*@dev",
        "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle" : "1.1.*@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "1.1.*@dev"

    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.1-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

And my **app/AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle(),
            new FOS\JsRoutingBundle\FOSJsRoutingBundle(),

        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }

    public function getCharset()
    {
        return 'UTF-8';
    }
}
```

The first fixture being loaded:

```
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture,
    Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\OrderedFixtureInterface,
    Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface,
    Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

use Acme\CoreBundle\Entity\User;

class LoadUserData extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container    = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }

    public function getOrder()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out where to look, `composer update` is running just fine.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution in [this issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineFixturesBundle/issues/73#issuecomment-12268057) on the repository of DoctrineFixturesBundle.

Rearranging the dependancies and using another version of `doctrine/data-fixtures` solved the problem.

I replaced these lines in my **composer.json**:

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "2.0.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "dev-master"
}
```

with

```
"require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle" : "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@ALPHA"
}
```

And the fixtures are being loaded again.

Comment: Don't use `@dev-master`. You can use `1.0.*@ALPHA`, which is stable enough.