# Container Dependecy Injection not working in Fixtures after upgrading symfony 2.0 to 2.1/2.2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.2

I upgraded a project from Symfony 2.0 to 2.1. After that my tests stopped working. The problem is that I use fixtures which implement the ContainerAware interface. Now after the upgrade the setContainer() method does not get called anymore. I tried upgrading further to 2.2. The problem still persists.

composer.json:

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.2.*",
    "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.5-dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
    "twig/extensions": "1.0.*@dev",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.1.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.2.*",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.4.*",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.1.*@dev",
"knplabs/knp-menu-bundle":"dev-master",
"knplabs/knp-menu":"dev-master",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*@ALPHA",
"doctrine/migrations": "dev-master",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/translation-bundle": "dev-master"


},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.2-dev"
    }
}
```

}

and my fixture looks like this:

LoadUserData.php

```
<?php
namespace FINDOLOGIC\CustomerLoginBundle\DataFixtures\ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;


class LoadUserData implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
     [...]
    }
}
```

I've already taken a look at [Doctrine fixtures not working after updating to Symfony 2.1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549240/doctrine-fixtures-not-working-after-updating-to-symfony-2-1-8) but it does not solve my problem.

I'm really looking forward to your input as I have been trying to solve this for quite a while now.

Comment: is it the injection not happening or is the whole fixture not loaded ?

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, nothing would fix it via changing round composer order, order in the kernal, extending or implementing etc, so in the end, I just pass the container in from the test:

```
public function testLogin()
{

///
$fixture = new UserFixtures();
$fixture->setContainer($container);
///

$executor->execute($loader->getFixtures(), true);
```

And now it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

**Solution:**

Make sure you not only implement ContainerAwareInterface - you should **extend ContainerAware**

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;

// ContainerAware... already implements ContainerAwareInterface

class YourFixture extends ContainerAware 
{
    // ...
```

**Another suggestion**:

Move Datafixtures further up in your composer.json ( before doctrine/orm ) to have composer generate the classmap correctly.

The [2.0 documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html) states.

> Be sure to register the new namespace before Doctrine\Common.
>   Otherwise, Symfony will look for data fixture classes inside the
>   Doctrine\Common directory. Symfony's autoloader always looks for a
>   class inside the directory of the first matching namespace, so more
>   specific namespaces should always come first.

Furthermore you don't need fixtures-bundle and fixtures as fixtures is a dependency of fixtures-bundle.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edit composer.json like you suggested and ran composer update. Sadly setContainer still does not get called.