# Container is non-object error in Symfony data fixtures

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to access to the service `api.service.feedback` in fixture class below but for some reason container returns error below on `if` statement in `load()` method:

**ERROR:** `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function has() on a non-object`

Note: If anyone wants to know, the service `api.service.feedback` itself is accessible in all the controllers and has no problem with it.

```
<?php

namespace .........;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\AbstractFixture;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LoadOrderFixtures extends AbstractFixture implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        if ($this->container->has('api.service.feedback')) {
            exit('EXISTS');
        }
     }

     ......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just implementing the ContainerAwareInterface. If you want the container, you have to inject it:

```
services:
    bundle.service_name: 
        class: ...
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ] ]
```

Comment: You don't need that! [Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html#using-the-container-in-the-fixtures)

Comment: @inanzzz you're right, according to documentation the container should be injected with `setContainer` just by implenting the `ContainerAwareInterface`. But apparently it's not happening. There's also a note in that doc: *If you are too lazy to implement the needed method setContainer(), you can then extend your class with ContainerAware.* Have your tried extending it?

Comment: @inanzzz this is weird, have you checked this question:? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789730/container-dependecy-injection-not-working-in-fixtures-after-upgrading-symfony-2

Comment: Just did it but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend directly ContainerAware:

```
class LoadArticlesData extends ContainerAware implements FixtureInterface, OrderedFixtureInterface {

    public function load(ObjectManager $manager)
    {
        $dummy = $this->container->getParameter('dynamic.dummy');
        ...   
    }
}
```